# Shorting the crystal

Tags: microcontroller, crystal

Just curious to know what will happen incase I short the Pin1 and Pin2 of my crystal while my board is ON. Crystal is connected to MPC5606S.

What will go wrong and why ?

[image]

Comment: Your oscillator will stop, and thus so will your microcontroller. Beyond that I can't say.

Comment: What happens to the crystal when we short ? and what impact it will have for the controller

Comment: @Newbie nothing because it's short...but the MCU pins trying to drive the short...

Comment: The crystal will be fine, nothing of note will happen to it. The microcontroller (or frequency synthesizer, or fpga, or whatever it is you have hooked up to the crystal) might be fine or it might damage itself from trying to drive the short. I couldn't say. Generally, just don't do this.

Comment: I am trying to understand whether shorting the crystal will damage the micro or not. I will not do this. Any insight I can get if I did this in terms of micro's internal architecture? i.e. if both crystal pins are ground, what will the micro do?

Comment: What would you expect?  Since the crystal provides the clock frequency, no clock.  No clock, no execution.  Micro cannot do anything, aside from possible damage to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: The internal circuit should withstand shorts. However, transient static discharges by connecting "probes" can destroy nearly anything.
From the datasheet, the internal circuit is current-limited by a current source "I" fed from the DC supply Vdd:
[image: data sheet internal oscillator block diagram]

When Vdd is 3.3V, DC voltage at **XTAL** and **EXTAL** pin should be near 0.95V. If so, chances are that the oscillator is still good to go. The oscillator merely stops oscillating while **EXTAL** is shorted to **XTAL**. The logic level may be *undetermined* at about 0.95V, which may confuse circuits connected to **EXTAL** downstream.
[image: data sheet oscillator spec]

Shorting **XTAL** to **EXTAL** should neither damage the MOSfet, the current source, or the external crystal. The current source "I" seems large @ 2mA spec in the data sheet.

- Shorting either **XTAL** or **EXTAL** to ground is current-limited to 2mA from the oscillator's current source "I"....no problem.
- It is unlikely that you've connected **EXTAL** to Vdd, but that's no problem...again, current is limited by the current source "I". When  **EXTAL** goes to logic high, **XTAL** should go from 0.95V to logic low. Doing this test would satisfy me that the oscillator is working OK.

Comment: Thank you. I have some doubts. How did you arrive at the 0.95V value? The value of R and I is not provided in the datasheet. And when you say downstream and current limited to "I", what does it mean?

Comment: @Newbie ….added edits. This oscillator is a primary signal source with no logic inputs. It does have an output which drives other parts of the clock chain....outputs are not shown in the diagram above (they'd be connected to **XTAL**). I'm calling anything on the output side "downstream logic". Current source "I" is shown in the circuit, along with a MOSfet, and "R" of unknown value.

Comment: thank you for the edits. Could u please simplify the 2points even more 1. "It is unlikely that you've connected EXTAL to Vdd, but that's no problem...again, current is limited by the current source "I". When EXTAL goes to logic high, XTAL should go from 0.95V to logic low. Doing this test would satisfy me that the oscillator is working OK." 2. "The oscillator merely stops oscillating while EXTAL is shorted to XTAL. The logic level may be undetermined at about 0.95V, which may confuse circuits connected to EXTAL downstream.".  Could you please simplify even more. Really appreciate it

Comment: Note that this oscillator is software configurable from a "run-mode" register: S_MTRANS bit (ME_GS register). On power-up, a different clock is chosen, and *this high-speed crystal clock* may be turned off. I'm assuming it is properly enabled...you should see 0.95V DC if it is enabled, 0V if it is disabled. All the clock source switching is done internally with run-mode register configuration. Data sheet essentially says, " don't mess with XTAL or EXTAL pins in an effort to disable or enable this clock".

Comment: I am seeing an average value of 1.40V on one end the crystal and 0.8V on the other end of crystal. It is a sine wave. Both the ends have 8MHz. But I didnt see 0.95V as you said that it would be the oscillating operation point.

Comment: @Newbie ...seems good. Once oscillating, DC biasing (average voltage) can shift. In addition to this, probe capacitance can affect the circuit. Data sheet says nothing about the acceptable *range* of the 0.95V operating point.

Comment: Thanks @glen_geek. Theoretically, you mean to say that I should observe that 0.95V while probing the crystal pins, right? But because of the probe capacitance, I am not able to get that voltage

Comment: With what instrument did you measure DC voltage? Even a 10MEGohm voltmeter can change DC voltage on these pins. The internal "R" is likely high-R and can be easily loaded by a voltage measurement (I'll bet **EXTAL** is the 0.8V pin). If you see 8 MHz, the oscillator is very likely working satisfactorily.

Comment: Measured in Oscilloscope

Comment: What did you mean by that Oscillation operating point? Can u tell its definition

Comment: continue in chat